# High voltage output from CCFL backlight transformer?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, crt, ccfl

I have an old television inverter board I've been meaning to turn into a power supply for a  plate-deflected oscilloscope CRT *. I'm not really an expert on transformers, however, and though I have pinouts and datasheets for the transformer in question [(4006A)](http://dalincom.ru/datasheet/4006A.pdf), I can't figure how I would recreate the conditions needed to create the HV output. I've seen schematics on creating CRT drivers from a different kind of CCFL transformer, but none with one like the one I have here. Can a transformer expert help me understand how I'd implement a transformer like this?

- Corrected from "mag deflected CRT".

Comment: what shape of core does your transformer have?  how much power are you wanting? do youy want to light up the whole CRT or just a trace?

Comment: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1jfsneA.HL1JjSZFuq6x8dXXaD/2pcs-New-4006A-Inverter-Transformer-for-V144-301-V070-001-good-quality.jpg_640x640.jpg

inside of the transformer
only looking for maybe 10mA to light up a scope trace

Comment: You cannot simply design anything without understanding how it works, All design questions need specs 1st.

Comment: CRT's use a high power Flyback for fast H sweep, not a low power CCFL supply for low current.  Not possible.

Comment: http://tubetime.us/index.php/2014/05/31/electrostatic-crt-driver-design/

oh?

Comment: your question mentions `mag deflected CRT` ... re-read the page that you linked in your comment

Comment: oh dear i misworded that didnt I...
i meant a plate-deflected oscilloscope CRT
apologies, very much my bad